# Calling a method in java and returning beer cost

Tags: java

What I am supposed to do:

> Add some necessary statements to the `printOrderCost()` method in the
>   main class so that this method computes and prints the total cost of
>   all beer items in the order. (This method calls the `getCost()` method
>   for each beer item, accumulates the sum of all of the `getCost()`
>   values, and then prints the sum – the total cost of all beer objects.)

Code:

```
public static void printOrderCost(Beer[] order)
 {
  double totalCost;
  int count;

 }


 }

 public double getCost()
 {
   double cost;
   cost = quantity * itemCost;
   return (cost);

 }

 public String toString()  // not necessary to format the output
 {
   String s;
   s = brand + " ";
   s += quantity + " " ;
   s += itemCost + " ";
   s += getCost();

   return s;


 }
```

Output:

```
Bud 5 3.0 15.0
Canadian 5 1.0 5.0
Blue 3 2.0 6.0
White Seal 4 1.0 4.0
Bud Light 1 2.0 2.0
```

Comment: 1) to see if it works, write code to test it. 2) to call the method in `toString()`, simply call it. Let's see what you come up with.

Comment: Don't remove your question after it's been answered...

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks fine to me. To call getCost() in toString() method, simply just call it with getCost().

So your toString() method should be something like this:

```
public toString(){
    String s;
    s = brand + " ";
    s += quantity + " " ;
    s += itemCost + " ";
    s += getCost();

    return s;
}
```

Hope this is what you're looking for :)

Comment: Fantastic, great job CodingBird, That is exactly what I am looking for, I really appreicate your help

Comment: Use `StringBuilder` instead of String and at return time convert it to `string`, this will help you proper memory management.

Answer (score 0):

From the code you have supplied, the `getCost` method "looks" fine

Your `toString` method should simply need to be appended to your `return` `String` `s`

```
public String toString()  // not necessary to format the output
{
    String s;
    s = brand + " ";
    s += quantity + " " ;
    s += itemCost + " ";
    s += getCost();
    return s;
}
```

You might also like to take a look at [`NumberFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/NumberFormat.html), which will allow you to control the output format, just in case you get a funny looking value ;)

Comment: Thanks MadProgrammer I appreciate your help

Answer (score 0):

It is generally a bad idea to add strings up like you did, as Java will create a unique String for each addition, which causes some unnecessary overhead. You can either use a StringBuilder as a general-purpose tool, or, if you know the exact format of how the String should look like, you can use String.format(...).

Example:

```
public toString() {
  return String.format("%-10s %2d %6.2f %6.2f", brand, quantity, itemCost, getCost());
}
```